# JSONata query ... feedback requested

Tags: jsonata

I am investigating JSONata as part of my quest to find a declarative syntax for describing transformations from hierarchical JSON data to traditional, normalized, relational tables.

[This](http://try.jsonata.org/BJcprxVsG) example uses the try.jsonata.org Invoice data and shows transformations to three RDBMS tables ... AccountTable, AccountOrderTable, AccountOrderProductTable.

Observe that I am iterating through the $.Account.Order array twice ... once to generate records for the AccountOrderTable and again to generate records for the AccountOrderProductTable. The closure captures $order so that the product entries have access to the parent $order.OrderID

While I'm OK with iterating over the $.Account.Order array twice, I am wondering if there is a clean way to construct the JSONata query so that the $map operation only gets applied once to each array.

Q: How could I construct this query (while generating the same resuls) so that I only $map the $.Account.Order array one time?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://try.jsonata.org/rJX-cgBoM) produces the same result, but uses a temporary binding to eliminate the double loop round the `Order` array.  Of course, you could argue that being a declarative language, the implementation should be responsible for optimising the evaluation.  But I suspect the implementor might not get round to this for a while.

Comment: Excellent. In addition to eliminating the double loop via the temp binding, your example demonstrates another important concept for me. Your query eliminates my explicit calls to $map and $reduce. Clearly I don't yet have a full understanding of the implicit $map in the dot (.) operator. I also continue to be surprised/perplexed by the sequence-like behavior of arrays ... my query had an explicit call to $reduce($append) in order to force array flattening but in your version of the query this simply vanished.